# Grep column value in same line and print line

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have this 5-columns file :

```
m64071_220512_054244/46858502/ccs TCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTTATTGGGCACGGTGTCGCCATCTGATCGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCGAGGTTTGCAGCTATTTTATTTACAAGTATACATTTAACACAATGAAATAAACACTGATATACTGAAGCCTAGTTAATAGTAGTGTAACAATATGCATCATTTTGATGATTACATTATTTTAAACAACAAACTACACTGAAAAATTAATGCCGATAAAATTCTTGGTCATAATATTAAGAAATACAATATATAAATTGAAAATATGATTGCTTAAAATTTGAAAATGGAAGTGAACTCATTTGGACAGACTCAGAGTTAACATAATCTGAAGGGAGGGGAGCTCTGACCCAAATGATATCTTTCAGGTTAACAGAAGAAAAAAGAAGCATAGTTTATCTTCAAGGAGAACGGGCAGTTTGCTTCTTCAGGTA fwd pet047-9952 TATTGGGCACGGTGTC
m64071_220512_054244/52233509/ccs AGCTTTTTTGGAATCTTCTGCTAAAGAAAATCAGACTGCTGTGGATGTTTTTCGAAGGATAATTTTGGAGGCAGAAAAAATGGACGGGGCAGCTTCACAAGGCAAGTCTTCATGCTCGGTGATGTGATTCTGCTGCAAAGCCTGAGGACACTGGGAATATATTCTACCTGAAGAAGCAAACTGCCCGTTCTCCTTGAAGATAAACTATGCTTCTTTTTTCTTCTGTTAACCTGAAAGATATCATTTGGGTCAGAGCTCCCCTCCCTTCAGATTATGTTAACTCTGAGTCTGTCCAAATGAGTTCACTTCCATTTTCAAATTTTAAGCAATCATATTTTCAATTTATATATTGTATTTCTTAATATTATGACCAAGAATTTTATCGGCATTAATTTTTCAGTGTAGTTTGTTGTTTAAAATAATGTAATCATCAAAATGATGCATATTGTTACACTACTATTAACTAGGCTTCAGTATATCAGTGTTTATTTCATTGTGTTAAATGTATACTTGTAAATAAAATAGCTGCAAACCTCGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACGATCAGATGGCGACACCGTGCCCAATAAGATCGGAAGAGCGTCGTGTAGA rev pet047-9952 GACACCGTGCCCAATA
m64071_220512_054244/91226755/ccs TCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTTATTGGGCACGGTGTCGCCATCTGATCGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCGAGGTTTGCAGCTATTTTATTTACAAGTATACATTTAACACAATGAAATAAACACTGATATACTGAAGCCTAGTTAATAGTAGTGTAACAATATGCATCATTTTGATGATTACATTATTTTAAACAACAAACTACACTGAAAAATTAATGCCGATAAAATTCTTGGTCATAATATTAAGAAATACAATATATAAATTGAAAATATGATTGCTTAAAATTTGAAAATGGAAGTGAACTCATTTGGACAGACTCAGAGTTAACATAATCTGAAGGGAGGGGAGCTCTGACCCAAATGATATCTTTCAGGTTAACAGAAGAAAAAAGAAGCATAGTTTATCTTCAAGGAGAACGGGCAGTTTGCTTCTTCAGGTAGAATATATTCCCAGTGTCCTCAGGCTTTGCAGCAGAATCACATCACCGAGCATGAAGACTTGCCTTGTGAAGCTGCCCCGTCCATTTTTTCTGCCTCCAA fwd pet047-9952 TATTGGGCACGGTGTC
```

For each line, I need to grep the last column value $5 in the second field $2.
Then, I need to print the same line with an additional $6 column with the grep result with a condition : `if ($3 == rev)` , the $6 is grep result + 12 characters after grep or `if ($3 == fwd)` the grep result + 12 characters before grep.

```
awk '$2~/$5/ {match($0, /$5/); if ($4=="rev") print substr($0, RSTART +12, RLENGTH + 12); else print substr($0, RSTART + 0, RLENGTH + 12) ;}' file
```

$5 values are necessary 16 characters and the pattern I look for is always 12 characters. Then, my $6 output is 28 characters.

Expected output :

```
m64071_220512_054244/46858502/ccs TCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTTATTGGGCACGGTGTCGCCATCTGATCGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCGAGGTTTGCAGCTATTTTATTTACAAGTATACATTTAACACAATGAAATAAACACTGATATACTGAAGCCTAGTTAATAGTAGTGTAACAATATGCATCATTTTGATGATTACATTATTTTAAACAACAAACTACACTGAAAAATTAATGCCGATAAAATTCTTGGTCATAATATTAAGAAATACAATATATAAATTGAAAATATGATTGCTTAAAATTTGAAAATGGAAGTGAACTCATTTGGACAGACTCAGAGTTAACATAATCTGAAGGGAGGGGAGCTCTGACCCAAATGATATCTTTCAGGTTAACAGAAGAAAAAAGAAGCATAGTTTATCTTCAAGGAGAACGGGCAGTTTGCTTCTTCAGGTA fwd pet047-9952 TATTGGGCACGGTGTC TATTGGGCACGGTGTCGCCATCTGATCG
m64071_220512_054244/52233509/ccs AGCTTTTTTGGAATCTTCTGCTAAAGAAAATCAGACTGCTGTGGATGTTTTTCGAAGGATAATTTTGGAGGCAGAAAAAATGGACGGGGCAGCTTCACAAGGCAAGTCTTCATGCTCGGTGATGTGATTCTGCTGCAAAGCCTGAGGACACTGGGAATATATTCTACCTGAAGAAGCAAACTGCCCGTTCTCCTTGAAGATAAACTATGCTTCTTTTTTCTTCTGTTAACCTGAAAGATATCATTTGGGTCAGAGCTCCCCTCCCTTCAGATTATGTTAACTCTGAGTCTGTCCAAATGAGTTCACTTCCATTTTCAAATTTTAAGCAATCATATTTTCAATTTATATATTGTATTTCTTAATATTATGACCAAGAATTTTATCGGCATTAATTTTTCAGTGTAGTTTGTTGTTTAAAATAATGTAATCATCAAAATGATGCATATTGTTACACTACTATTAACTAGGCTTCAGTATATCAGTGTTTATTTCATTGTGTTAAATGTATACTTGTAAATAAAATAGCTGCAAACCTCGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACGATCAGATGGCGACACCGTGCCCAATAAGATCGGAAGAGCGTCGTGTAGA rev pet047-9952 GACACCGTGCCCAATA CGATCAGATGGCGACACCGTGCCCAATA
m64071_220512_054244/91226755/ccs TCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTTATTGGGCACGGTGTCGCCATCTGATCGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCGAGGTTTGCAGCTATTTTATTTACAAGTATACATTTAACACAATGAAATAAACACTGATATACTGAAGCCTAGTTAATAGTAGTGTAACAATATGCATCATTTTGATGATTACATTATTTTAAACAACAAACTACACTGAAAAATTAATGCCGATAAAATTCTTGGTCATAATATTAAGAAATACAATATATAAATTGAAAATATGATTGCTTAAAATTTGAAAATGGAAGTGAACTCATTTGGACAGACTCAGAGTTAACATAATCTGAAGGGAGGGGAGCTCTGACCCAAATGATATCTTTCAGGTTAACAGAAGAAAAAAGAAGCATAGTTTATCTTCAAGGAGAACGGGCAGTTTGCTTCTTCAGGTAGAATATATTCCCAGTGTCCTCAGGCTTTGCAGCAGAATCACATCACCGAGCATGAAGACTTGCCTTGTGAAGCTGCCCCGTCCATTTTTTCTGCCTCCAA fwd pet047-9952 TATTGGGCACGGTGTC TATTGGGCACGGTGTCGCCATCTGATCG
```

But I do not get what I want.

Comment: In future questions please create and post [mcve]s, emphasis on **minimal**, so it's easiest for us to understand your problem and test a potential solution so we can help you. Posting input with lines almost 700 characters long is not useful. We shouldn't need to use scroll bars to understand any part of your question, you could have posted sample input with, say, 3 lines of 4 fields of 3-5 characters each and still demonstrated your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below script to achieve your result:

```bash
awk '{
    idx = index($2, $5);
    if (idx != 0) {
        if ($3 == "rev") {
            substr_28 = substr($2, idx - 12, 28);
        } else {
            substr_28 = substr($2, idx, 28);
        }
        print $0, substr_28;
    }
}' your_file_containing_inp
```

Basically, the script:

1. first finds the index of the `$5` value in the second field. If the value is found `(idx != 0)`.

   a. it checks the value of the third field.
   b. If it's `"rev"`, it extracts the `28-character` substring starting 12 characters before the index.
   c. else, it extracts the substring starting at the index.

***[CODE DEMO](https://replit.com/@msankrit/CelebratedMelodicApi#main.sh)***

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will do it, using any awk:

```
awk 'match($2,$5) {
        print $0, ( $3 == "fwd" \
                    ? substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH+12) \
                    : substr($2,RSTART-12,RLENGTH+12) \
                  )
    }' file
m64071_220512_054244/46858502/ccs TCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTTATTGGGCACGGTGTCGCCATCTGATCGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCGAGGTTTGCAGCTATTTTATTTACAAGTATACATTTAACACAATGAAATAAACACTGATATACTGAAGCCTAGTTAATAGTAGTGTAACAATATGCATCATTTTGATGATTACATTATTTTAAACAACAAACTACACTGAAAAATTAATGCCGATAAAATTCTTGGTCATAATATTAAGAAATACAATATATAAATTGAAAATATGATTGCTTAAAATTTGAAAATGGAAGTGAACTCATTTGGACAGACTCAGAGTTAACATAATCTGAAGGGAGGGGAGCTCTGACCCAAATGATATCTTTCAGGTTAACAGAAGAAAAAAGAAGCATAGTTTATCTTCAAGGAGAACGGGCAGTTTGCTTCTTCAGGTA fwd pet047-9952 TATTGGGCACGGTGTC TATTGGGCACGGTGTCGCCATCTGATCG
m64071_220512_054244/52233509/ccs AGCTTTTTTGGAATCTTCTGCTAAAGAAAATCAGACTGCTGTGGATGTTTTTCGAAGGATAATTTTGGAGGCAGAAAAAATGGACGGGGCAGCTTCACAAGGCAAGTCTTCATGCTCGGTGATGTGATTCTGCTGCAAAGCCTGAGGACACTGGGAATATATTCTACCTGAAGAAGCAAACTGCCCGTTCTCCTTGAAGATAAACTATGCTTCTTTTTTCTTCTGTTAACCTGAAAGATATCATTTGGGTCAGAGCTCCCCTCCCTTCAGATTATGTTAACTCTGAGTCTGTCCAAATGAGTTCACTTCCATTTTCAAATTTTAAGCAATCATATTTTCAATTTATATATTGTATTTCTTAATATTATGACCAAGAATTTTATCGGCATTAATTTTTCAGTGTAGTTTGTTGTTTAAAATAATGTAATCATCAAAATGATGCATATTGTTACACTACTATTAACTAGGCTTCAGTATATCAGTGTTTATTTCATTGTGTTAAATGTATACTTGTAAATAAAATAGCTGCAAACCTCGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACGATCAGATGGCGACACCGTGCCCAATAAGATCGGAAGAGCGTCGTGTAGA rev pet047-9952 GACACCGTGCCCAATA CGATCAGATGGCGACACCGTGCCCAATA
m64071_220512_054244/91226755/ccs TCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTTATTGGGCACGGTGTCGCCATCTGATCGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCGAGGTTTGCAGCTATTTTATTTACAAGTATACATTTAACACAATGAAATAAACACTGATATACTGAAGCCTAGTTAATAGTAGTGTAACAATATGCATCATTTTGATGATTACATTATTTTAAACAACAAACTACACTGAAAAATTAATGCCGATAAAATTCTTGGTCATAATATTAAGAAATACAATATATAAATTGAAAATATGATTGCTTAAAATTTGAAAATGGAAGTGAACTCATTTGGACAGACTCAGAGTTAACATAATCTGAAGGGAGGGGAGCTCTGACCCAAATGATATCTTTCAGGTTAACAGAAGAAAAAAGAAGCATAGTTTATCTTCAAGGAGAACGGGCAGTTTGCTTCTTCAGGTAGAATATATTCCCAGTGTCCTCAGGCTTTGCAGCAGAATCACATCACCGAGCATGAAGACTTGCCTTGTGAAGCTGCCCCGTCCATTTTTTCTGCCTCCAA fwd pet047-9952 TATTGGGCACGGTGTC TATTGGGCACGGTGTCGCCATCTGATCG
```

FYI for future questions, here's what a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could have looked like, using `2` instead of `12` as the number of additional chars to print:

Sample input:

```
$ cat file
this abcdefghi fwd foobar cd
that abcdefghi rev bar de
other abcdefghi fwd foo ef
```

Expected output:

```
this abcdefghi fwd foobar cd cdef
that abcdefghi rev bar de bcde
other abcdefghi fwd foo ef efgh
```

which we could then test with to easily see if the potential solution works or not:

```
awk 'match($2,$5) {
        print $0, ( $3 == "fwd" \
                    ? substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH+2) \
                    : substr($2,RSTART-2,RLENGTH+2) \
                  )
    }' file
this abcdefghi fwd foobar cd cdef
that abcdefghi rev bar de bcde
other abcdefghi fwd foo ef efgh
```

Comment: It is too long, you're right. But your code works, thanks.

Comment: I don't think it did work for the "rev" case so I just changed it.

Comment: Actually, I just change `substr($2,RSTART+0,RLENGTH+12) : substr($2,RSTART+12,RLENGTH+12)` to get 28 characters.

Comment: That won't print the "grep result" as you said you wanted, it'll skip the first 12 characters of it. You said you wanted the "grep result" plus 12 chars before or after it - the code in your comment won't do that and there's no reason to hard-code `28` to do it.

Comment: I just checked any my code produces exactly the expected output you show in your question. I updated my answer to show that.